# adding const before the brackets in c++

Tags: c++, oop

Just wondering why the syntax for virtual functions uses a const before the curly braces, as below:

```
  virtual void print(int chw, int dus) const;
```

Incidentally, the code doesnt seem to work without the const, which is interesting.. not sure why?

many thanks!

Comment: there are no curly braces in your example... Took me a moment to figure out what you meant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `const` in the function signature signifies a *const member function* - Anthony Williams gave a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98705/what-are-the-semantics-of-a-const-member-function) on the implications.
Note that there is nothing special about *virtual member functions* functions in that regard, *constness* is a concept that applies to all non-static member functions.

As for why its not working without - you can't call non-const members on a const instance. E.g.:

```
class C {
public:
  void f1() {}
  void f2() const {}
};

void test() 
{
    const C c;
    c.f1(); // not allowed
    c.f2(); // allowed
}
```

Comment: @gf: *constness* only applies to *non-static* member functions.

Comment: If it *compiles* without const, but doesn't *work* as expected (with is what "doesn't work" normally means), then the reason is most likely different. This `const` is a part of function signature. Const and non-const versions are different functions, which are overridden independently. For example, if you remove `const` from a virtual function in base class of the hierarchy and keep it in the derived classes, the functions in the derived classes will no longer override the function in the base class. The virtual functionality will fall apart and the code will no longer "work" as it used to.