# Quick one about const in c++

Tags: c++, methods, constants, return

I understand that the correct way to declare a return type const is to write:

```
int foo() const;
```

But in some cases this doesn't work for me, then I can use:

```
const int foo();
```

What is the difference between these, and why can I use the latter in all cases but not the first one.

An example of where I can't use the first one is when I want to return an array of bools that are defined outside of the method.

Kind regards,

/Markus

Comment: `int foo() const;` does not make the return type `const`. It means that `foo()` is a member function of a class, and `foo()` promises not to make any changes to the `*this` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand that the correct way to declare a return type const is to write:
>
> ```
> int foo() const;
> ```

Your understanding is not correct. What the above does is declare `foo()` as a `const` member function. This has nothing whatsoever to do with `foo()`'s return type.

For more info, see [What are the semantics of a const member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98705/what-are-the-semantics-of-a-const-member-function)

Answer (score 3):

`int foo() const;` says that `foo()` as a member function won't modify the data members of the class.

`const int foo();` says that `foo()` is a function whose return value is a `const int`(an `int` indeed).

Comment: Actually, `int const foo()` declares a function whose return type is `int`.  A function can't have a return type of `int const`, since the non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types.

Answer (score 2):

The former one is used in class's method function. It means this method function doesn't (logically) change the data of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Only the second example declares the return type as const. So if you want to return a const value, that's the way to do it (and the only way I believe)

The first snippet states that the `this` pointer in a non-static member function points to a const object (i.e. the method will not modify the object).

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
int foo() const;
```

and

```
int foo();
```

are a pair of functions you may define as a class member function. Their return type are all **int**.

When a **const** object of that class call function **foo()**, the first one will response.

This function

```
const int foo();
```

can be define everywhere. the return type is **const int**, so you must assign the function to a **const int** variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo() const;
```

This does not declare the return type `const`. It declares that it's a `const` member function: it can be called on a `const` object, and is not allowed to modify any (non-`mutable`) members of the object.

```
const int foo();
```

This declares that the return type is `const`; but there's not much point in doing that.

Comment: Does it?  The return type of a function is a _prvalue_ (if it is not a reverence), and _prvalues_ of non-class type are never cv-qualified, so either `int const foo()` is illegal, or it declares a function with a return type of `int`.  (I'd prefer it to be illegal, but I think for historical reasons, it's accepted, and the `const` is ignored.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's probably ignored partly because it's redundant (there's no way to modify it, with or without the const), and partly for consistency with class types (one less special case the standard has to account for when using templates!)

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde It's ignored because the standard says very clearly that rvalues (prvalues in C++11) of non-class types are not cv-qualified.  This goes back to C (where rvalues are not cv-qualified, period).  That is to say: you cannot have an rvalue (prvalue) of type `int const`, since such things don't exist in the language.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You're right, it doesn't; I should have checked my assumptions before answering.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, I get that the standard says so, and it makes perfect sense that prvalues can't be cv-qualified. I was just trying to offer a probable reason for why the committee decided on ignoring these cv-qualifiers, as opposed to making them illegal.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde The reason C++ ignores them is because C ignored them:-).  As for why C ignored them, the reason you give seems as good as any other, and fits into the philosophy of C (which is basically to make as little as possible an error.)

Answer (score 1):

The first one means that the method will not change any class member variables (directly or indirectly). This basically means that no class member can be assigned in this method and only `<method> () const` can be called in the body of the method.

The second one means that the returned value cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` modifies what is immediately before it; in

```
int foo() const;
```

it is the function which is const, not the return value.  (By
definition, a function is const if the type of its `this` pointer is a
pointer to const.  Only member functions can be const.)

To make the return type const, place the `const` immediately after the
return type, e.g.:

```
int const foo();
```

Note however that this const is ignored for non-class types; the return
value will be an rvalue (a temporary), and only class type rvalues have
cv qualified types.  (I think some compilers will even warn about the
above.)